# Advanced search with mongoose

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, search

I have an query object

```
const query = {
brand : BMW,
yearFrom : 2000,
yearTo : 2003,
price : 7000,
};
```

I am trying to find every BMW which is made between 2000 and 2003 included.
I am trying in this way but it doesn't work

```
 if (query.yearFrom) {
        return  offerModel.find({query,year : {$gte : query.yearFrom  }}, function(err,arr) {console.log(err,arr)}).skip(offset).limit(12);
       
    }
```

Here's the mongoose schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const offerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    brand: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    model: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    year: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    color: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    power: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    mileage: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    populatedState: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    condition : {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    doors: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    transmission: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    engineType: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    category: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    imageURLs : [],
    imageIds : [],
    creator: {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'user'
    },
})




module.exports = mongoose.model('offers', offerSchema);
```

Sample data from database

```
_id:60fe98301b76642e04a31c45,
imageURLs:[],
imageIds : [],
brand:BMW,
model:335,
year:2000,
color:White,
doors:4,
power:130
mileage:30000,
populatedState:Sofia,
price:7000,
condition:Used,
description:qweqweqweqe,
transmission:Automatic gearbox,
engineType:Petrol,
category:Sedan,
creator:60fe97d11b76642e04a31c44,
__v:0,
```

If i put only query it find brand,model and etc.But it doesn't get year search correctly.

I will be glad if you guys have some ideas how can i fix that
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
offerModel.find({
      $and: [
          { brand :query.brand  },
         year : {
            $gte: query.yearTo, 
            $lt: query.yearFrom
        }
      ]
  }, function (err, results) {
      ...
  }
```

Comment: It returns empty array. In my example above also returns empty array

Comment: @zhpbg sample dataset

Comment: Sorry , what do you mean?

Comment: give me mongoose schema and few sample data

Comment: I've edited the post cuz i can not leave long comments.You can see the mongoose schema and sample data above